# How soon can one return to US with visitor visa?

Tags: visas, usa

How long do you have to be out of the country before you can return on a visitor visa?  My sister in law will be traveling from a Central American country that requires a visa to visit the USA (she does not qualify for the Visa Waiver Program).  Ideally, I'd like her to stop by for a few days as she travels to Europe for a couple months and then stay for a longer visit when she returns back from Europe.

Comment: Do you mean an actual visa that you apply for? How long were you in the US before? What is your reason for traveling? Please edit the question to add extra data.

Comment: What country are we talking about? How long will she stay/go?

Comment: Not sure why this is marked duplicate as the other question is about visiting under the visa waiver program and my question is about traveling to the USA on a visitor visa.